# Можно ли как-то опубликовать Docker-приложение более просто для использования, чем на DockerHub?

Tags: docker

Например, я решил сделать программу для домохозяек на основе микросервисной архитектуры (пример очень грубый и приведён исключительно для понимания сути вопроса). Естественно, я использовал Docker, чтобы собрать сервисы в единый рабочий механизм. Но для целевого пользователя моего ПО – домохозяек – может показаться непреодолимой сложностью установка Docker и ввод ряда команд в PowerShell, даже при наличии подробнейшей инструкции.

Вопрос: есть ли какой-либо другой способ опубликовать приложение, созданное с помощью Docker? Причём способ, позволяющий пользователю установить и использовать приложение гораздо более просто, чем описано выше. Идеалом был бы какой-нибудь установщик, где весь алгоритм сводится к Далее -> Далее -> Далее -> Завершить.

Comment: Написать скрипт в упомянутом PowerShell который всё сделает сам?

Comment: @nobody Скачает Docker, установит его, спуллит образ и запустит? Не трудновато для скрипта на PowerShell? И всё-таки, я думаю, пользователю хотелось бы видеть какой-то граф. интерфейс.

Comment: А в чём сложность, простите? Если сомневаетесь, можно создать инсталлятор с помощью Inno Setup или банального winrar (вроде там было средство для создания "красивых менюшек"). Не ясно какой абстрактной домохозяйке нужен интерфейс. Можно установить банальный portainer, если это слишком сложно для домохозяйки, ну ок, абсолютно все UI/WebUI docker работают через его API, просто берёте и пишите свой интерфейс на чём угодно где будет одна кнопка - "сделать хорошо". В общем, это какой-то расплывчатый вопрос, решений есть множество.

Comment: @nobody *решений есть множество* опишите, пожалуйста, наиболее простое из них, и это будет прекрасный ответ.

Comment: Прочитайте выше, пожалуйста. Там описан вариант. В ходе разработки, в случае, если появятся конкретные вопросы, задайте отдельно с примерами нерабочего кода.

Comment: @nobody Ладно, спасибо

Comment: Самое простое скрипт для сборки образа, откачки исходников и их сборки